# Pass Selection value to query as field name

Tags: php, html

Basically in Query "Option 1" should change based on selection from drop down
assuming drop down field are heading in my table and wanted to SET heading name dynamically

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="first">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

assuming drop down field are heading in my table and wanted to SET heading name dynamically

```
$query = ("UPDATE Table SET "Option 1"  ='".$Test."'  WHERE ID= '$ID'");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652144/how-to-change-content-depending-on-a-select

Comment: you realize that your query failed

Answer (score 0):

Firstlly set "name='first'" attribute in "select" tag.

Now if "Option 1", "Option 2",... are already feilds in database table, then you can put condition like this,

```
if(isset($_POST['first']) && !empty($_POST['first'])){
   $query = "UPDATE Table SET 'Option ".$_POST['first']."' =".$Test." WHERE ID= '$ID'";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use php variable

```
<select id="first">
   <option value="<?php echo $arr['val1']; ?>"><?php echo $arr['val1']; ?></option>
   <option value="<?php echo $arr['val1']; ?>"><?php echo $arr['val2']; ?></option>
   <option value="<?php echo $arr['val3']; ?>"><?php echo $arr['val3']; ?></option>
   <option value="4"><?php echo $arr['val4']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Thats not at all what he wants to do.